# Моргает ASCII анимация на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решил Написать небольшой mp3 плеер для командной строки. Пока занимался анимацией возникла проблема - анимация моргает когда обновляется кадр. Вот видео: https://youtu.be/in4VLPOfzHw.
А также код:

```
import time, os, glob, eyed3, math, sys
from colorama import init
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3


mpts = glob.glob('*.mp3')
dark_grey = '\033[1;30;40m'
light_grey = '\033[0;37;40m'
white = '\033[1;37;40m'
lime = '\033[1;32;40m'
red = '\033[0;31;40m'
i = 0
song_list = []

for mpt in mpts:
    song = MP3(mpt)
    duration = math.ceil(song.info.length)
    m_duration = duration // 60
    s_duration = duration % 60
    song = eyed3.load(mpt)
    name = song.tag.title
    song_list.append([name, [m_duration, s_duration]])

init()

# draw
while True:
    # cassette
    res = ''
    i += 1
    res += light_grey + '  ■̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅■   \n'
    res += dark_grey + ' |'
    res += light_grey + '|############|'
    res += dark_grey + '| \n'
    res += dark_grey + ' |'
    res += light_grey + '|'
    if i % 4 == 0:
        res += white + ' (/)====(/) '
    elif i % 4 == 1:
        res += white + ' (-)====(-) '
    elif i % 4 == 2:
        res += white + ' (\\)====(\\) '
    elif i % 4 == 3:
        res += white + ' (|)====(|) '
    res += light_grey + '|'
    res += dark_grey + '| \n'
    res += dark_grey + ' |'
    res += light_grey + '|############|'
    res += dark_grey + '|\n'
    res += light_grey + '  ■____________■   \n'
    # green line
    res += lime + ' ___________________________________\n\n'
    # song list
    res += red + ' #  NAME                        TIME\n'
    for i1 in range(len(song_list)):
        res += dark_grey + ' ' + str(i1+1) + '.'
        res += white + ' ' + song_list[i1][0] + ' '*(28 - len(song_list[i1][0])) + f'{song_list[i1][1][0]}:{song_list[i1][1][1]}\n'
    os.system('cls')
    sys.stdout.write(res)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.4)
```

Возможно ли это как-то исправить, или же лучше попробовать написать на чем-то другом?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вместо полной очистки консоли через `cls` просто перемещайте курсор в левый верхний угол консоли и рисуйте каждый новый кадр поверх старого, тогда моргания не будет:

```
while True:
    # cassette
    res = ''
    i += 1
    res += light_grey + '  ■̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅■   \n'
    res += dark_grey + ' |'
    res += light_grey + '|############|'
    res += dark_grey + '| \n'
    res += dark_grey + ' |'
    res += light_grey + '|'
    if i % 4 == 0:
        res += white + ' (/)====(/) '
    elif i % 4 == 1:
        res += white + ' (-)====(-) '
    elif i % 4 == 2:
        res += white + ' (\\)====(\\) '
    elif i % 4 == 3:
        res += white + ' (|)====(|) '
    res += light_grey + '|'
    res += dark_grey + '| \n'
    res += dark_grey + ' |'
    res += light_grey + '|############|'
    res += dark_grey + '|\n'
    res += light_grey + '  ■____________■   \n'
    # green line
    res += lime + ' ___________________________________\n\n'
    # song list
    res += red + ' #  NAME                        TIME\n'
    for i1 in range(len(song_list)):
        res += dark_grey + ' ' + str(i1+1) + '.'
        res += white + ' ' + song_list[i1][0] + ' '*(28 - len(song_list[i1][0])) + f'{song_list[i1][1][0]}:{song_list[i1][1][1]}\n'
    # os.system('cls')
    print('\033[H', end='')  # <--- Переместить курсор в левый верхний угол консоли
    sys.stdout.write(res)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.4)
```

Также есть смысл рамку кассеты рисовать один раз, а в цикле перерисовывать только меняющуюся часть. В этом случае нужно перемещаться не в верхний левый угол, а на конкретную позицию:

```
# cassette frame
res = ''
res += light_grey + '  ■̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅■   \n'
res += dark_grey + ' |'
res += light_grey + '|############|'
res += dark_grey + '| \n'
res += dark_grey + ' |'
res += light_grey + '|            |'
res += dark_grey + '| \n'
res += dark_grey + ' |'
res += light_grey + '|############|'
res += dark_grey + '|\n'
res += light_grey + '  ■____________■   \n'
# green line
res += lime + ' ___________________________________\n\n'
print(res)

# draw
while True:
    i += 1
    # cassette wheels
    print('\033[3;5H', end='')  # Переместить курсор на 3 строку, 5 столбец
    if i % 4 == 0:
        print(white + '(/)====(/)')
    elif i % 4 == 1:
        print(white + '(-)====(-)')
    elif i % 4 == 2:
        print(white + '(\\)====(\\)')
    elif i % 4 == 3:
        print(white + '(|)====(|)')

    # song list
    res = '\033[8;1H'  # Переместить курсор на 8 строку (ниже кассеты)
    res += red + ' #  NAME                        TIME\n'
    for i1 in range(len(song_list)):
        res += dark_grey + ' ' + str(i1+1) + '.'
        res += white + ' ' + song_list[i1][0] + ' '*(28 - len(song_list[i1][0])) + f'{song_list[i1][1][0]}:{song_list[i1][1][1]}\n'
        
    sys.stdout.write(res)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.4)
```

Информация о перемещении курсора из этого ответа: [Move console cursor up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40104556)

---

Дальше рекомендации по улучшению кода.

Вот эту строку можно сильно упростить:

```
# Было
res += white + ' ' + song_list[i1][0] + ' '*(28 - len(song_list[i1][0])) + f'{song_list[i1][1][0]}:{song_list[i1][1][1]}\n'

# Стало
res += white + f' {song_list[i1][0]} {song_list[i1][1][0]:>28}:{song_list[i1][1][1]}\n'
```

При итерации по последовательности со счетчиком вместо `range` принято использовать `enumerate`, escape-последовательности можно подставлять прямо в f-строку, получается такой цикл:

```
for i1, song in enumerate(song_list, start=1):
    res += f'{dark_grey} {i1}. {white} {song[0]} {song[1][0]:>28}:{song[1][1]}\n'
```

Ну и если список песен не меняется, то его отображение тоже можно вынести до цикла `while`.

Comment: Спасибо, цикл for уже исправил. Также решил подключить модуль asciimatics, и как оказалось он для этой задачи подходит просто идеально, он позволяет отдельно отрисовывать определенные элементы по координатам (строка, столбец), при этом не затрагивая никакие другие.